# Cancel order in cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob, orders

is it possible for a customer to cancel an order in cartthrob? E.g. he buys a ticket but recognizes that he does not have time to go to the event. So he wants to cancel his order.

Does anybody has an idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give users acces to your order channel? Show them of course only their own orders, and let them edit or delete.
Only problem exists if they have already payed. In that case a mail to the shop owner with all the details?
An inbetween option would be a time slot. Delay the actual money withdrawal, giving customers opportunity to cancel/alter the order. After that, no refund possible, unless against some costs.

Comment: I'd suggest you don't allow them to edit or delete the order, but change the status from say 'Paid' to 'Customer Cancelled'. This would make spotting the customer cancelled orders easier in the CP. Dealing with payment is the tricky part as I don't think this could be automated easily so it comes down to your terms of sale.